# Can I have multiple data sources in spring without specifying the primary one?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

The situation is as follows.
I have a microservice that imports a module. I want that module to be reusable by other microservices and to have it's own data source.

I managed to do this by manually configuring the data source in the module (in a @Config glass), but if I want to import the module, I also have to manually configure my data source in each micro service and specify that it's the primary one.

Is there any way to only configure the module's data base and to let spring do it's automatic config inside the microservices? Thanks, any help is appreaciated.

Comment: Some project structure would help, is it a multi module maven/gradle project? Your single module can have appliction.properties or yml of its own which can define its database

Comment: It's a multi module gradle project. Both the microservice and the imported modules have their own application.yml where the properties are defined. I believe some issues might also arise by the first yml file being overwritten by the second one, but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: No in case of absence of yml in module, the parent yml comes in effect but higher priority is given to closest property defined